# hash for comparision of objects in java

Tags: java, hash

i need to compare two objects in java, it should be tested if their attributes have the same values. Instead of simply compare all the attributes i was thinking about using hash functions. Therefore i have written the following code

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException; 
import java.util.Vector;

public class Test {

private static Vector<String> vecA, vecB;

public static void main(String args[]) {
    vecA = new Vector<String>();
    vecB = new Vector<String>();

    vecA.add("hallo");
    vecA.add("blödes Beispiel");
    vecA.add("Einer geht noch");
    vecB.add("hallo");
    vecB.add("blödes Beispiel");
    vecB.add("Einer geht noch");

    System.out.println("HashCode() VecA: " + vecA.hashCode());
    System.out.println("HashCode() VecB: " + vecB.hashCode());

    System.out.println("md5 VecA: " + md5(vecA));
    System.out.println("md5 VecB: " + md5(vecB));

    vecA.add("ungleich");

    System.out.println("HashCode() VecA: " + vecA.hashCode());
    System.out.println("HashCode() VecB: " + vecB.hashCode());

    System.out.println("md5 VecA: " + md5(vecA));
    System.out.println("md5 VecB: " + md5(vecB));

}

private static String md5(Vector<String> v){
    try {
        MessageDigest algorithm = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        algorithm.reset();
        algorithm.update(vecA.toString().getBytes());
        byte messageDigest[] = algorithm.digest();

        StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < messageDigest.length; i++) {
            String hex = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]);
            if (hex.length() == 1)
                hexString.append('0');
            hexString.append(hex);
        }
        return hexString.toString();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae) {}
    return null;
}
}
```

The md5 function is simply copied by some website. This leads to the following output

```
HashCode() VecA: -356464767
HashCode() VecB: -356464767
md5 VecA: 6805716958249f5b7f177fc95408713e
md5 VecB: 6805716958249f5b7f177fc95408713e
HashCode() VecA: 1477685990
HashCode() VecB: -356464767
md5 VecA: c76297ce297d5308359ca06f26fb97ca
md5 VecB: c76297ce297d5308359ca06f26fb97ca
```

I am confused that adding an element in vecA seems to change the md5 Code of vecB and so their hashes are still the same. Whats the reason and is their any advantage in using  java.security.MessageDigest or simply hashCode() in that case? How about the performance of hash functions vs. comparisons of all attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're building the md5 hash for vecA in both cases:

```
algorithm.update(vecA.toString().getBytes());
```

should probably be

```
algorithm.update(v.toString().getBytes());
```

> Whats the reason and is their any advantage in using java.security.MessageDigest or simply hashCode() in that case?

One advantage of not using `hashCode` would be that if that method is not overridden, two instances of the same class and with the same attribute values would still return different hashes, due to the default implementation of `hashCode`.

> How about the performance of hash functions vs. comparisons of all attributes?

If you just compare the attributes once, there might not be any noticable performance difference (that, however, depends on how you compare the attributes) but in case of repeatedly comparing a number of attributes vs. calculating a hash once and repeatedly comparing the hashes, the latter might be faster.

**Edit**:

Here's an example to clarify the answer to the first quote.
Consider the following simple piece of code:

```
static class A {   
   int x; 

   public A( int i) {    
    x = i;
   }
 }


static  class B {
   int x; 

   public B( int i) {    
    x = i;
   }

  public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    return prime * x;
  }

  public boolean equals( Object obj ) {
    //by contract you should always override equals and hashCode together
    //also note that some checks are omitted for simplicity's sake (obj might be null etc.)
    return getClass().equals( obj.getClass()) && x == ((B)obj).x;
  }
}
```

As you can see, `A` doesn't override `hashCode` while `B` does. Thus you'll get the following result:

```
System.out.println(new A( 500 ).hashCode() == new A(500).hashCode());  //false
System.out.println(new B( 500 ).hashCode() == new B(500).hashCode());  //true
```

Note that x is the same in both cases but for `A#hashCode()` the object identity is used, not the value of x as does `B#hashCode()`

Comment: Thanks so far, but i don't get the point "two instances of the same class and with the same attribute values would still return different hashes". Aren't vecA and VecB instances of the same Class with the same attribute values? Because their HashCode() are the same, that was one thing i wanted to test with my little program

Comment: @user3214281 That's why I said `if that method is not overridden` (meaning `hashCode`). `Vector` has a non-default implementation provided by `AbstractList`, which uses the elements' hash code instead the object identity provided by the JVM. I'll add an example.

Comment: All right, now i understand. Didn't know that Vector uses a "special" version of hashCode(). Looks like i have chosen the wrong class for my example. :) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in your md5 method

```
algorithm.update(vecA.toString().getBytes());
```

Probably should be

```
algorithm.update(v.toString().getBytes());
```

Comment: Also, I wouldn't use MD5 if you care about performance, I would use ``java.util.zip.Adler32``.  It is "good enough" for a hash and probably 10-100x faster than MD5.